# curl https time_appconnect is zero

Tags: linux, ssl, curl

my company has a web project, named `projectA`, is deployed in a cloud server(similar as AWS).
`projectA` is in tomcat.

we have ssl certificate, e.g. `mycompany.com`, users are able to access `projectA` by typing `https://mycompany.com/projectA` which will be redirected to `https://mycompany.com/projectA/loginPage.action` page if user has not login(only type `https://mycompany.com` will show 404 page), the browsers shows this website is secured.

however, either `curl -w "TCP handshake:%{time_connect}, SSL handshake: %{time_appconnect}\n" -so /dev/null https://mycompany.com` or `curl -w "TCP handshake:%{time_connect}, SSL handshake: %{time_appconnect}\n" -so /dev/null https://mycompany.com/projectA`, or `curl -w "TCP handshake:%{time_connect}, SSL handshake: %{time_appconnect}\n" -so /dev/null https://mycompany.com/projectA/loginPage.action` their `time_appconnect` are zero, why? `time_connect` has value.

i run `curl` in a cloud server whose CentOS is 7.9.2009(Core), Linux version 3.10.0, curl version is 7.29.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing intermediate certificate causes this problem, although we can use this webapp `projectA` normally in browser.

after concat server certificate and intermediate certificate to produce `.keystore`, this problem solved. With the help of ssl checker, we can found that the ssl deployment is correct or not.